# Django not cleaning data

Tags: django, django-forms

Somehow Django is not cleaning data from the form below:

```
class userRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    tos = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
```

View:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hash_object = hashlib.sha512(b'Hello World')
        hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

        form = userRegistration(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = User()
            user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
   else:
        form = userRegistration()

   return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

However, if I type "    some_username" (there are spaces before first character) into the input box that exact data is saved into the database, i.e. no .strip() method is called, therefore I presume that form data is not cleaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cleaned_data` is the validated data, but the contents are not stripped automatically. You'll need to write a `clean_username()` method on your form to do that for you. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) is the Django documentation on how to do this - you'd want something like:

```
def clean_username(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['username'].strip()
```